# Could not load NIB in bundle how to solve

Tags: ios, objective-c

NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'MapViewController

Comment: Post your code, how you load nib?

Comment: Do you actually have a xib named `MapViewController.xib`?

Comment: See there is spelling mistake or something else. First you post related code, then it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments: Check the naming for spelling mistakes.

Also check your `Copy Bundle Resources` if the .xib is added to your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning your project from Product-> Clean

or you can just remove reference the files (MapViewController) from your project, then you re-import the files in your project.

hope this helps you.